# Failed to open a connection to the database; MySQL.Data.MySQLClient; Cannot create a design window for the selected object

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio

I am using

- Visual studio 2017, version 15.9.11
- MySQL for visual studio 1.2.9
- MySQL-8.0.18-win64
- mySQL-connector-net-8.0.18-noinstall

If I try to add a connection to a project via `Data Sources > Database > Dataset`, and set the connection with the right server name, user name, and password, and then select one table, select options and click `Next` I get the following error

> "Failed to open a connection to the database 
>  Cannot obtain
>   provider factory for data provider named 'MySql.Data.MySQLClient'.
> Check the connection and try again."

[image]

Also, when I connect to a local MySQL database using `Tools > Connect to database...` and I create the connection, which successfully seems to be done in the server explorer, and then in the same `server explorer panel`, if I go `Data Connections > localhost > tables > double-click on the table`, this is the error I get:

> Cannot create a design window for the selected object.

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**

As I said in my question I had `mysql-connector-net-8.0.18-noinstall` extracted. I tend to extract binaries instead of installing things. Don't really have a good reason for this behavior.
After checking Vignesh solution and before uninstalling anything, I decided to give a try to the `mysql-installer-community-8.0.18.0.msi` installer, since I had the `mysql-connector-net-8.0.18-noinstall` extracted in one folder and then I added a reference in the project, which was not working. 
Perhaps there was a way to use this folder (binaries, global references, etc) properly, but I couldn't find one. Maybe I was the problem.

---

**The solution**

However, after installing via the `msi` file, everything is working now. So if you ran into this problem, having similar versions than the ones I'm using and had the `no-install` version extracted, you can safely close Visual Studio, and install the same version via the `msi` installer, this worked for me! 
Worst case scenario, you can uninstall it via the same `msi` file, and try Vignesh's or other's solution.

Answer (score 0):

This error will be fixed by uninstalling **`Connector current version`** and installing **`Connector 6.9.8`**

[**Download Connector 6.9.8**](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/)

**Visual Studio 2015:** `Visual Studio 2015 Community` + `DotNet Connector 6.9.8` + `MySQL for Visual Studio 2.0.3` is working combination.

**Visual Studio 2017:** `Visual Studio 2017 Community` + `DotNet Connector 6.9.8` + `MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7` is working.

Comment: I'll try that and let you know how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: First give a try without changing `MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7` and just install `Connector 6.9.8`

Comment: And you can get `MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7` from here https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/visualstudio/

Comment: Thanks. I deleted last message, because I realized that from the link you posted to Download Connector 6.9.8 I could access the archives for other MySql products, just the second after asking.

Comment: I'm testing it with a test project but it seems to be solved by installing the same connector I was using via the msi installer